# Doctrine: sortable behaviour and auto_increment colums

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have added this annotation to a column in my entity using symfony + doctrine annotations.

```
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

Now, after trying to migrate the database using "migrate diff", it says there is no changes to migrate. So how can I convert that field to auto_increment?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="position_brand", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $positionBrand;
```

**NOTE**: as you can guess because the name of the column, Im trying to implement a sortable behaviout. I know there are already made solutions, but I what to try to make it by myself.